# how can i display the alert message when two checkbox is checked using jquery?

Tags: jquery

When i checked the two checkbox then alert message cannot display. so how can i display the error message?

```
<body>
    <div class="float0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="c" value="first">
        <label for="c"><strong>ABC</strong>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="float0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="d" value="second">
        <label for="d"><strong>PQR</strong>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#c').is(":checked") && $('#d').is(":checked")) {
        alert('i m here');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  if ($('#c').is(":checked") && $('#d').is(":checked")) {
    alert('i m here');
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="float0">
  <input type="checkbox" id="c" value="first">
  <label for="c"><strong>ABC</strong>
  </label>
  <br>
</div>
<div class="float0">
  <input type="checkbox" id="d" value="second">
  <label for="d"><strong>PQR</strong>
  </label>
  <br>
</div>
```

1. Put the code inside change event for the checkbox.
2. Right now you are checking if the checkbox is checked on load not when the time the checkbox is being checked

Comment: @softwaredeveloper2 np mate glad to help close the OP by checking the check mark :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use change() event of checkbox to detect if both checkboxs are checked or not:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
    if ($('#c').is(":checked") && $('#d').is(":checked")) {
       alert('i m here');
    }
 })   
});
```